# How to retrieve component by name using the Core Service?

Tags: core-service, 2013

I'm using Tridion 2013 and creating components within a folder in Tridion. Its possible these components may have the same name, which obviously Tridion does not allow.

I'm using the following code to check whether an item with a given name already exists, and if so return a unique title string:

```
protected string GetUniqueTitle(string title, string folderId)
{
    return GetUniqueTitle(title, folderId, 1);
}

protected string GetUniqueTitle(string original, string folderId, int current)
{
    var title = string.Format("{0} {1}", original, current);

    var filter = new SearchQueryData
    {
        Title = title,
        IsTitleCaseSensitive = false,
        ItemTypes = new[] {ItemType.Component},
        SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData {IdRef = folderId},
        SearchInSubtree = false
    };

    var component = (ComponentData) _client.GetSearchResults(filter).FirstOrDefault();

    if (component != null)
    {
        return GetUniqueTitle(original, folderId, current + 1);
    }

    return title;
}
```

This code is working fine, but I've noticed during testing that if I quickly create multiple components with the same name, using this method to get a unique title, `_client.GetSearchResults(...)` will return `null` for the last one created.

Presumably this is because `GetSearchResults` uses Tridion's search index behind the scenes and this has not been populated quickly enough.

This is not likely to be a problem in practice, but it would be nice to be able to avoid it entirely.

So, my question is, is there another way to retrieve a component by name, or to check that a given name already exists within a folder?

I could simply try to create the component and catch the exception, but this would involve checking the exception message, which seems a bit hacky, as the Core Service always throws a WCF `FaultException`.

Any help, as always, much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass the WebDAV URL in the id parameter of IsExistingObject. Most (if not all) places the core service accepts an id you can use either a WebDAV URL or a TCM URI.

Notice you can read an object so you get all WebDAV URLs instead of TCM URIs as well, simply set the ReadOptions.LoadFlags to LoadFlags.WebDavUrls.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code below  -

```
var filter = new SearchQueryData
{
    Title = title,
    IsTitleCaseSensitive = false,
    ItemTypes = new[] {ItemType.Component},
    SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData {IdRef = folderId},
    SearchInSubtree = false
};

var component = (ComponentData) _client.GetSearchResults(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

But, it returns null instead of component search result. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please open a new question for this.